# Extracting x value given y threshold from polyfit plot (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-extraction

[image][image]

As shown by the solid and dashed line, I'd like to create a function where I set a threshold for y (Intensity) from that threshold it gives me corresponding x value (dashed line). Very simple but my while statement is off. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
%% Curve fit plotting %%

x1 = timeStamps(1:60); % taking timestamps from 1 - 120 given smoothed y1 values 
y1 = smooth(tic_lin(1:60),'sgolay',1);


% Find coefficients for polynomial (order = 4 and 6, respectively)
fitResults1 = polyfit(x1',y1, 7);

% evaluate the fitted y-values
yplot1 = polyval(fitResults1,x1');

% interpolates to find yi, the values of the underlying function Y at the points in the vector or array xi. x must be a vector. 
Time_points = interp1(yplot1, x1', yplot1);


figure( 'Name', 'Curvefit1_poly' );
h = plot(x1', y1);%smoothed-points
hold on;
plot(x1', yplot1);%polyfit points
hold on;
plot(Time_points, yplot1, '*r');%interpolated points of x given y


%given y-threshold, output x(corresponding time_point).
broken = false;

while broken == false
    if yplot1 >= 2024671226502.99
        index = find(yplot1);
        xDesired = x1(index);
        broken = true;
    else
        disp("next iteration through");
    end
end
```

Comment: If your problem is finding `x` given a certain value of `y` you can just pass the `x`,`y` coordinates in reverse order into the interpolation function. If it's a one-to-one mapping this will work.

Comment: Basically I'm wanting to set y to a certain threshold, and then from that threshold find x value within a function, and then have a final variable set to that x-value. I tried what you mentioned before and I still got multiple answers.

Comment: Aside: Not sure what you're aiming to do with the `interp1` function... You're interpolating from and to the same basis, so the output will be the same as the input.

Comment: What do you think `if yplot1 >= ....` is doing?  And what do you think `index = find(yplot1)` is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `while` loop is needed here... You can do this with logical indexing for the threshold condition and `find` to get the first index:

```
% Start with some x and y data
% x = ...
% y = ...

% Get the first index where 'y' is greater than some threshold
thresh = 10; 
idx = find( y >= thresh, 1 ); % Find 1st index where y >= thresh

% Get the x value at this index
xDesired = x( idx );
```

Note that `xDesired` will be empty if there was no `y` value over the threshold.

---

Alternatively, you already have a polynomial fit, so you could use `fzero` to get the `x` value on that polynomial for a given `y` (in this case your threshold).

```
% x = ...
% y = ...

thresh = 10;
p = polyfit( x, y, 3 ); % create polynomial fit

% Use fzero to get the root of y = a*x^n + b*x^(n-1) + ... + z when y = thresh
xDesired = fzero( @(x) polyval(p,x) - thresh, x(1) )
```

Note, this method may give unexpected results if the threshold is not within the range of `y`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I was having trouble because my output was essentially all the values greater than my threshold value, I was not getting only one value. I thought using interp1, and overlaying those values with my curve fit would be enough to just call my x given a set y. Thank you for the help.

Comment: As a function, would it be something like this?  function [xDesired, idx] = AT_point(x1, y1) and then add your code above below the function?

Comment: @DMD yeah that looks sensible, as long as the input names match the variables used (as in I used `x` and `y` but you've put `x1` and `y1`), you'd also probably want to input the threshold value. I mean the code could just be one line if you don't create the temporary variable `idx`, so a separate function might be overkill....

Comment: Im just going to have multiple curves so i'm going to need to set a global threshold, and then call my function. So say I have a global threshold, I'd put in my code: If thresh is >= 1e13 [xDesired, idx] = AT_point(x1,y1,thresh)....This is in hope I get multiple xDesired values across an image...Reference image I attached with the red grid..Im going to to have curve fit values (i.e., y) for each little box.